# EntityValidationException is thrown when saving my entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I got this message when debugged in `catch (Exception e)`. When User fill in all the information, `Address and Payment` `View` will get the `SalesOrderID` and redirect to Complete View. But it didn't show the Complete when it done.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(SalesOrderHeader order,Customer customer, Address address ,FormCollection values)
        {
             ViewBag.PersonType = new SelectList(new[] { "EM", "SC", "VC", "IN" } // work
                                                    .Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
                                                    "value", "text");
            try
            {
                if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
                {
                    return View(order);
                }
                else
                {
                    order.AccountNumber = User.Identity.Name;
                    order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
                    address.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now; // maybe this error
                    order.Address.PostalCode = "12345";

                    //Save Order
                    BikeDBs.SalesOrderHeaders.Add(order);
                    try
                    {
                        BikeDBs.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                    {
                        foreach (var entityValidationErrors in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                        {
                            foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Properties: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //Process Order
                    var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                    cart.CreateOrder(order);
                    //cart.CreateOrder(order1);
                    return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = order.SalesOrderID });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //Invalid - redisplay with errors
                return View(order);
            }
```

All I want is when the `Order` is saved, it will redirect to `Complete`. But in this case, it's not. And here is `Address` model:

```
public partial class Address
    {
        public Address()
        {
            this.SalesOrderHeaders = new HashSet<SalesOrderHeader>();
            this.SalesOrderHeaders1 = new HashSet<SalesOrderHeader>();
        }

        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int StateProvinceID { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public System.Guid rowguid { get; set; }
        [Required()]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual StateProvince StateProvince { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderHeaders { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderHeader> SalesOrderHeaders1 { get; set; }
    }
```

What's a solution and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your logic in `if(ModelState.IsValid){ // add order and redirect } return View(order); // show errors`? That *should* catch your EF validation errors. When you do get EF validation errors you should show the form again anyway and not continue on since that probably won't make any sense to show the next page if the previous one failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily by using the `ModelState`, it should catch it. If it doesn't I added code into your catch block to catch it and display the page again with the errors using `ModelState.AddModelError`.

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(SalesOrderHeader order,Customer customer, Address address ,FormCollection values)
{
    ViewBag.PersonType = new SelectList(new[] { "EM", "SC", "VC", "IN" } // work
                                                .Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
                                                "value", "text");
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.Equals(values["PromoCode"], PromoCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == false)
            {
                return View(order);
            }
            else
            {
                order.AccountNumber = User.Identity.Name;
                order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
                order.Address.PostalCode = values["PostalCode"];

                //Save Order
                BikeDBs.SalesOrderHeaders.Add(order);
                try
                {
                    BikeDBs.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    foreach (var entityValidationErrors in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            // If this far add errors to model errors and show view again.
                            ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                            Console.WriteLine("Properties: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                    return View(order);
                }
                //Process Order
                var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
                cart.CreateOrder(order);
                //cart.CreateOrder(order1);
                return RedirectToAction("Complete", new { id = order.SalesOrderID });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(order);
        }
    }
    return View(order);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I still got one error `Error Message = "The PostalCode field is required."` Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: @TrungPham are you seeing that on the view? You should because it means your model requires that field to have a value and you're not submitting a value or it's not able to map the form field to you object (typo in form field name?). Can you do a break point and verify that your model has no null fields?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address.ModifiedDate): 
@Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("ModifiedDate")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.ModifiedDate)`. I set up in View like that. Is it wrong? Because it still threw an old error.

Comment: @TrungPham Looks fine, does your view have the `PostalCode` field in it also?

Comment: I've edited my question, can you review it and let me know if I have a problem.

Comment: Yes, I also have the `PostalCode` field in View @siva.k!

Comment: @TrungPham I can't say I see anything particularly wrong. I would recommend using the `ModelState.IsValid` as shown in my answer if you haven't already. Without being able to see your model and the HTML being generated I honestly can't tell you why it's not coming in properly or why it's throwing that exception. As just a comment on your code style you may benefit from flattening your model and instead of using your EF models create a model just for the view (more MVVM style), besides better logical separation it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: Neither can I see what's wrong with them. I'm struggling with it, I updated `Address`model for more specific in my question. @siva.k

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49617/discussion-between-siva-k-and-trung-pham)

Answer (score 1):

*For my answer I assume that the properties `PostalCode` and `PersonType` are of type `string` and are defined as `not nullable`.*

I think the error messages you get clearly say what the problem is. The properties `PostalCode` and `PersonType` are required, that means they need to have a value other than `null`.

So when you do not set the properties to a value other than null and you try to save your entity you will get the error messages.

**To fix it** you will net to set the properties to some values (maybe a default value) or you have to change your EntityModel to specify that these properties are `nullable`

Comment: `[Required(ErrorMessage = "PostalCode is required")]
  public string PostalCode { get; set; }`. I fixed it like that, but it still got the error and it has one `Error Message = "The PostalCode field is required."`

Comment: @TrungPham do you checked the value that is set on PostalCode when you save your entity?

Comment: `Nullable: False` when I set it true and it get an error caused the Entity is not matched @Jehof

Comment: @TrungPham Please read documentation of RequiredAttribute ->http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I put a `[Require()]` above `public Nullable<System.DateTime>ModifiedDate {get; set;}` in `Address` Model. It still got that error, I don't know @Jehof